# What justifies the lvalue category of unevaluated non-static data members in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, decltype

Both gcc and clang accept the following code, and I'm trying to figure out why.

```cpp
// c++ -std=c++20 -Wall -c test.cc

#include <concepts>

struct X {
  int i;
};

// This is clearly required by the language spec:
static_assert(std::same_as<decltype(X::i), int>);

// This seems more arbitrary:
static_assert(std::same_as<decltype((X::i)), int&>);
```

The first `static_assert` line makes sense according to [dcl.type.decltype]:

> otherwise, if E is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access ([expr.ref]), decltype(E) is the type of the entity named by E. If there is no such entity, or if E names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
>
> - https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.type.decltype#1.3

`X::i` is a valid [id-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.id#2.3) in an unevaluated context, so its decltype should be the declared type of `i` in `X`.

The second `static_assert` has me stumped.  There's only one clause in [dcl.type.decltype] in which a *parenthesized* expression yields an lvalue reference: it must be that both compilers consider `X::i` to be an expression of lvalue category.  But I can't find any support for this in the language spec.

Obviously if `i` were a *static* data member then `X::i` would be an lvalue.  But for a *non-static* member, the only hint I can find is some non-normative language in [expr.context]:

> In some contexts, unevaluated operands appear ([expr.prim.req], [expr.typeid], [expr.sizeof], [expr.unary.noexcept], [dcl.type.simple], [temp.pre], [temp.concept]).
> An unevaluated operand is not evaluated.
> [ Note: In an unevaluated operand, a non-static class member may be named ([expr.prim.id]) and naming of objects or functions does not, by itself, require that a definition be provided ([basic.def.odr]).
> An unevaluated operand is considered a full-expression.
> — end note
> ]
>
> - https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prop#expr.context-1

This suggests `decltype((X::i))` is a valid type, but the [definition of full-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.execution#def:full-expression) doesn't say anything about value categories.  I don't see what justifies `int&` any more than `int` (or `int&&`).  I mean an lvalue is a glvalue, and a glvalue is "an expression whose evaluation determines the identity of an object."  How can an expression like `X::i`--which can't be evaluated at all, let alone determine the identity an object--be considered a glvalue?

Are gcc and clang right to accept this code, and if so what part of the language specification supports it?

**remark:**
StoryTeller - Unslander Monica's answer makes even more sense in light of the fact that [`sizeof(X::i)` is allowed](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim#id-2.3) and that `decltype((X::i + 42))` is a prvalue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can an expression like `X::i--which can't be evaluated at all, let alone determine the identity an object--be considered a glvalue?

Ignoring the misuse of «result», it is [[expr.prim.id.qual]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.id.qual#2):

> A *nested-name-specifier* that denotes a class, optionally followed by the keyword `template` ([temp.names]), and then followed by the name of a member of either that class ([class.mem]) or one of its base classes, is a *qualified-id*; ... The result is an lvalue if the member is a static member function or a data member and a prvalue otherwise.

The value category of an expression is not determined by the «definition» in [basic.lval], like «an expression whose evaluation determines the identity of an object», but specified for each kind of expression explicitly.

Comment: The spec is confusing (particularly the use of result as you point out), but this is helpful, thanks.    Not sure why someone downvoted you back to zero after I upvoted you, but I appreciate the reference.

Comment: @user3188445 the use of the «result» word here predates the current definition of «result». It seems CWG folks don't bother cleaning up wording when they add a new term. This happened not only to «result».

Answer (score 11):

> How can an expression like `X::i`--which can't be evaluated at all, let alone determine the identity an object--be considered a glvalue?

That's not entirely true. That expression *can* be evaluated (following a suitable transformation in the right context).

> **[class.mfct.non-static]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.mfct.non-static#3.sentence-1) When an id-expression that is not part of a class member access syntax and not used to form a pointer to member ([expr.unary.op]) is used in a member of class X in a context where this can be used, if name lookup resolves the name in the id-expression to a non-static non-type member of some class C, and if either the id-expression is potentially evaluated or C is X or a base class of X, the id-expression is transformed into a class member access expression using (*this) as the postfix-expression to the left of the . operator.

So we can have something like

```
struct X {
  int i;
  auto foo() const { return X::i; }
};
```

Where `X::i` is transformed into `(*this).X::i`. Which is explicitly allowed on account of

> **[expr.prim.id]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.id#2.1) An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - as part of a class member access in which the object expression refers to the member's class or a class derived from that class, or ...

And that meaning of `(*this).X::i` is always an lvalue denoting the class member `i`.

So you see, in the contexts where `X::i` *can* be evaluated, it always produces an lvalue. So `decltype((X::i))` in those context would *need* to be an lvalue reference type. And while outside of class scope `X::i` cannot generally be used in an expression, it's still not entirely arbitrary to say its value category is an lvalue. We are just expanding the region of definition a bit (which doesn't contradict the standard, since the standard doesn't define it).

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler be required to issue a diagnostic though, since the parentheses force it to treat `X::i` as an expression, but it's not a valid expression in this context? The fact that it's unevaluated doesn't somehow change that. If the compiler wants to yield `int&` as an extension, fine, but it should still issue a diagnostic.

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself correctly. I guess it's still an expression even when it's unparenthesized. But at least in the unparenthesized case, it seems that the standard specifically makes it defined by giving a rule as to what it means. In the parenthesized case, the rule is just "treat it like you would treat an expression in any other context, but don't evaluate it". So it should be ill-formed.

Comment: @Brian - As it were, it is at most undefined, and not in violation of a diagnosble rule. At least not one I could find. It's explicitly allowed in an unevaluated operand https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.id#2.3 - But the meaning isn't all there.

Comment: Aha, I forgot about that rule. Yep, I guess it's not ill-formed after all. It's really too bad that the standard doesn't define what the `decltype` is supposed to be here.

Answer (score -1):

The root of your question seems to be the difference between `decltype(X::i)` and `decltype((X::i))`. Why does `(X::i)` yield a `int&`? See:

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.type.decltype#1.5

> otherwise, if E is an lvalue, decltype(E) is T&, where T is the type of E;

However, the key point here is that the fact that it yields a `T&` doesn't really matter:

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.type#1

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression. [ Note: Before the lifetime of the reference has started or after it has ended, the behavior is undefined (see [basic.life]). — end note ]

What "justifies" it then? Well, when doing `decltype(X::i)` we're concerned primarily with what the type of `X::i` is and not its value category or its properties when treated as an expression. However, `(X::i)` is there if we *do* care.

Comment: But do you have an answer to my question?  What justifies the lvalue category for `X::i` when `i` is a non-static member?  I think we both agree that if `X::i` is an lvalue, then `decltype((X::i))` is an`int&`.  But what part of the spec justifies it being an lvalue in the first place?